# error with composor (install / update ) with laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

installed laravel template built on version 4.2 , when i make composer (install / update) I still have this error with composer .

> Problem 1
>   - Installation request for d11wtq/boris v1.0.10 -> satisfiable by d11wtq/boris[v1.0.10].
>   - d11wtq/boris v1.0.10 requires ext-pcntl * -> the requested PHP extension pcntl is missing from your system.
>   Problem 2
>   - d11wtq/boris v1.0.10 requires ext-pcntl * -> the requested PHP extension pcntl is missing from your system.
>   - laravel/framework v4.2.17 requires d11wtq/boris ~1.0 -> satisfiable by d11wtq/boris[v1.0.10].
>   - Installation request for laravel/framework v4.2.17 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v4.2.17].

Comment: So, you need `pcntl` extension. Read manuals and install it. Then run composer again.

Comment: can i do that on windows ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the package [`d11wtq/boris`](https://github.com/borisrepl/boris) needs the [Process Control Extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) (`pcntl`) of PHP. To install `pcntl` compile the CGI- or CLI version of PHP with `--enable-pcntl`.

> **Note:**
> Currently, this module will not function on non-Unix platforms (Windows).

So hopefully you use something like linux or mac os.

Comment: actually I use Windows

Comment: OK bad for you :( it will not work with Windows. All you could do is using a virtual machine with Linux or e.g. laravel homestead.