# laravel/framework v4.2.9 requires d11wtq/boris ~1.0 -> no matching package found

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I have following composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "zizaco/entrust": "1.2.*@dev",
        "zizaco/confide": "~4.0@dev",
        "mailchimp/mailchimp": "~2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0",
        "intervention/image": "2.2.1",
        "webpatser/laravel-uuid": "1.*",
        "hugofirth/mailchimp": "2.0.*",
        "jenssegers/agent": "~2.1",
        "roumen/sitemap": "2.4.15",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~1.3.0",
        "tecnick.com/tcpdf": "6.2.*",
        "anhskohbo/no-captcha": "1.*",
        "tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles": "^1.5",
        "mailgun/mailgun-php": "~1.7.2",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~3.0",
        "rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer": "^0.5.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "way/generators": "~2.3",
        "Codeception/Codeception": "~2.0",
        "league/factory-muffin": "^2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Benu\\": "app/Benu"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

After running `composer install I get following error:

> laravel/framework v4.2.9 requires d11wtq/boris ~1.0 -> no matching
>   package found.

I have tried minimal dependencies in json:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "way/generators": "~2.3"
},
```

But the error is the same. Here is full output:

[image]

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: maybe this can help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31100735/error-with-composor-install-update-with-laravel-4-2

Comment: The requested package d11wtq/boris ~1.0 exists as d11wtq/boris[dev-master] but these are rejected by your constraint. It seems that version of the package is not available and it's called inside the framework itself /vendor/laravel/framework/composer.json