# Laravel Composer Error "no matching package found"

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am working with a team using Git on a project that uses laravel and composer. Where I have to clone the repository and change the configuration to work on my machine.

one of the configuration is to install the package dependencies using  `composer install` command

I was working on the project with the team normally without changing anything to **composer.json** file. Additionally I am using `Laravel Framework version 5.2.39` and `PHP 5.5.36` and it's different than the versions that specified on the **composer.json** file.

I had to make a copy of the project with a different name (because an issue with merge branches) and clone the repository again from github and do the configuration again

when I tried to install the dependencies using composer I get this error:

[image]

While if I try to install the dependencies on the old project (it's the same project with the same **composer.json**) I don't get any problem

[image]

this is the content of **composer.json**:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "way/generators": "2.*",
        "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*",
        "chrisbjr/api-guard": "0.*",
        "parse/php-sdk": "1.1.*",
        "ktamas77/firebase-php": "dev-master",
        "toin0u/geotools-laravel": "0.2.*",
        "firebase/token-generator": "^3.0"

    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

I tried to change laravel/framework from

```
"laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
```

To 5.2.* since my version is `5.2.39`

```
"laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
```

When I try again `composer install` I received a new error message

[image]

Does anyone face similar error?

Comment: it seems that there is a problem with d11dtq/boris package. Someone just asked the same question minutes ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38433548/laravel-framework-v4-2-9-requires-d11wtq-boris-1-0-no-matching-package-found

Comment: Is the PCNTL extension loaded? `echo "extension=pcntl.so" >> /path/to/php.ini` or append `--ignore-platform-reqs` to the Composer cmd to ignore the extension dependency.

Comment: Looks like a temporary issue, give it a day or two and it should be fixed.

Comment: @ntzm yes it was temporary issue, I test it this morning and it worked

Answer (score 1):

As what Mr. [ntzm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2977133/ntzm)

> [Looks like a temporary issue, give it a day or two and it should be
>   fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38436762/laravel-composer-error-no-matching-package-found#comment64284507_38436762)

I tested today and it works fine with me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your **composer.json** file update the following line

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
```

It was saying 4.2. 
And then update composer.